# Replace print func newline char for life of program

Tags: python, html, printing

Is there a single point where I can replace the print function newline char with a different one that will persist for the life of a program?
I am aware you can pass an `end` char to print but this becomes a hassle to do for every single call.

The program interfaces with a legacy system and can be called from both a terminal emulator or through the website. This is how I am currently handling it.

```
if(web):
    linebr='<br/>'
else:
    linebr='/n'
# export linebr

... # elsewhere
print(what,end=linebr)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new function that works as a customization of Python `print()` function. For example:

```
def print_(s):
    print(s, end="<br>")
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Now it will print correctly for web but not in a terminal. And with this approach I won't be able to change end when printing to a terminal.